# How to set a cookie for jwt token in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies

I am trying to authenticate a user from Angular 2 app by calling an express api that provides a JWT token upon success. I have got a doubt to clear.

Do we ask express to set the cookie or is it Angular job to set a cookie with the token

```
    loginUser(email: string, password: string) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        let loginInfo = { email: email, password: password };

        return this.http.post('/auth/login', JSON.stringify(loginInfo), options)
        .do(resp => {
            // Do I need to set the cookie from here or it from the backend?
        }).catch(error => {
            return Observable.of(false);
        })
    }
```

Comment: I think Angular will do the job. You can use even a local storage.

Comment: Please keep in mind though, should anyone follow Yonas suggestion. Using local storage would open up what ever you store there to XSS. Never store anyhing in local storage that would be considered a secret.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent how about when done in a cookie? is the app still vulnerable for XSS?

Answer (score 7):

You need to do it using Angular. Yes you can use **localStorage** suggested but better to be use **Cookie**.

here is a sample of code which i had used in my angular2 application.

> login.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AjaxLoader } from '../shared/services/ajax-loader';
import { UserService } from '../shared/services/user.service';
import { AuthCookie } from '../shared/services/auth-cookies-handler';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private userService: UserService,
    private ajaxLoader: AjaxLoader,
    private _authCookie: AuthCookie) {
    this.ajaxLoader.startLoading();

    this.loginInfo = new User();
    this.registrationInfo = new User();
  }

  validateUserAccount(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    this.userService.validateUserAccount(this.loginInfo)
        .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
            if (data.user === "Invalid") {
                this.isInvalidLogin = true;
            } else {
                    this._authCookie.setAuth(JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);

            }
        },
        error => {
            if (error.status === 404) {
                this.isInvalidLogin = true;
            }
            this.ajaxLoader.completeLoading();
        },
        () => {
            this.ajaxLoader.completeLoading();
        }
        );
    }
}
```

> auth-cookies-handler.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

@Injectable()
export class AuthCookie {
    constructor() { }

    getAuth(): string {
        return Cookie.get('id_token');
    }

    setAuth(value: string): void {
        //0.0138889//this accept day not minuts
        Cookie.set('id_token', value, 0.0138889);
    }

    deleteAuth(): void {
        Cookie.delete('id_token');
    }  
}
```

And in your Component you can use below lines to validate AuthCookie.

```
if (!_this._authCookie.getAuth()) {
    _this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a more simplistic way of doing this?

Comment: @eugensunic Yes. you can simply import Cookie and use get() and set() methods. however I wrote this because i had to use DI layer in my application for common used classes.

Comment: I've used your class already, however I did some additional object parsing to retrieve the object key. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with Angular. I personally use localStorage for that.

Example from my auth service:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    const body = { email, password };
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/authenticate', body)
        .map(response => {
            const jsonRes = response.json();
            if(jsonRes.status == 'success') {
                // Auth token
                localStorage.setItem('auth_token', jsonRes.data.token);
            }
            return jsonRes;
        })
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```